# Pandas to_excel using utf-8 encoding appears not to work

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I'm trying to write a dataframe to .xlsx, but this fails. I've tried two different approaches but get the same error for both, so presumably it's something else.

Approach 1:

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'encoding':'utf-8'})
    for k in data_output:
        data_output[k].to_excel(writer, k, encoding='utf-8')
    writer.save()
```

Approach 2:

```
    for k in data_output:
        data_output[k].to_excel(k + '.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
```

Each time the file/files just contains:

> Error! [file path] is not UTF-8 encoded
>   Saving disabled.
>   See Console for more details.

My understanding is that by specifying utf-8 encoding the output would be in that format and I shouldn't see such an error. Approach 2 but changing to .to_csv runs without any problems and I get the data into the files. So I'm wondering if this is a bug in .to_excel, or if there is just something I'm doing wrong here (really hoping for the latter). Thankful for help!

(I'm doing this in Jupyterhub, don't see how that would affect this issue but I'm not an expert.)

Comment: Try this:
`writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'encoding':'utf-8'})
data_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
writer.save()`

Comment: I've tested this and it yields exactly the same as above, so it does not appear to solve the issue.